# Is it possible to redeclare a const in c?

Tags: c, scope, constants, declaration, c99

I've come across a piece of code where the same **const** variable is redeclared several times in a for-loop, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
  int integer;
  bool boolean;
} mystruct_t;

void main (void) {
  int i;
  uint8_t *buf;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    const mystruct_t mystruct = {
      .integer = i,
      .boolean = 0
    };
    memcpy(buf, &mystruct, sizeof(mystruct));
  }
  return;
}
```

Is this allowed according to the c standard (I'm using c99)? If so, what is the motivation behind redeclaring **struct** in every iteration?

Comment: Only a single variable of type `mystruct_t` is ever declared, but it's initialised as many times as the loop is executed - each time being initialised to a different value. And scoping means it's not accessible outside the for loop

Comment: In C, the keyword `const` should be interpreted as "read-only", which means the variable cannot be changed after its initialization. This means the compiler will print an error message if you try to modify the variable.

Comment: When asking questions like this, please provide a [mre]. This code does not compile, which introduces some confusion about what needs to be answered.

Comment: Does a minimal reproducible example have to compile? I thought I could omit the inclusion of the standard libraries because it's trivial.

Comment: You may want to use a [compound literal](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.5) instead: `memcpy(buf, &(mystruct_t){ .integer = i, .boolean = 0 }, sizeof (mystruct_t));`

Comment: Why would I want to use a compound literal instead? You linked to the c11 standard, I'm using c99.

Comment: Fixed link for C99. Using a compound literal does not create an identifier.

Comment: @LukesDiner: A [mre] should generally also include all `#include` directives. It is extra work for someone trying to reproduce the error to look through your code and to write all necessary `#include` directives. But, most importantly, including the full code demonstrates that your example is complete and reproducible. To me, code without any `#include` directives is a big warning flag. If these directives are missing, then in my experience, there is a very high probability that there is also other important stuff missing, making the problem not reproducible.

Comment: @LukesDiner: A minimal reproducible example must be **reproducible**. The missing three includes are not the only reason the original code would not compile: It used the keyword `struct` as an identifier, it had semicolons instead of commas in an initializer, and it used statements outside of a function. While it is easy for an experienced programmer to correct these mistakes, they do not generally know which ones might be causing compiler messages that are confusing a learner and leading to some misunderstanding. And, even if they can correct them, it is a nuisance.

Comment: `void main (void)` is not a strictly conforming declaration. Use `int main(void)`.

Comment: Conforming according to what? Using void main(void) is perfectly fine when you don't need to return a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you may not use the keyword `struct` as a variable name.

```
  const mystruct_t struct = {
                   ^^^^^^
```

The for loop has its own block scope. When a block scope gets the control recursively like in this code snippet

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  const mystruct_t struct = {
    .integer = i;
    .boolean = 0;
  };
  memcpy(buf, &struct, sizeof(struct));
}
```

then the constant variable of the type `mystruct_t` is created anew.

From the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 6 **For such an object that does not have a variable length array
> type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
> associated until execution of that block ends in any way.** (Entering
> an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
> execution of the current block.) **If the block is entered
> recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time. The
> initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is
> specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or
> compound literal is reached in the execution of the block;**
> otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration
> is reached.

So neither variable is redeclared in your code snippet. In each iteration of the for loop a new instance of the variable with the same name is created. The variable is declared with the qualifier `const` because it is not being changed within the block scope of the for statement. As the variable is not used outside the for statement then it is declared in the minimal scope where it is used.

Comment: The question asks "possible?", "allowed?" and "motivation?". I am not clear which of those questions this post answers.

Comment: The bolded text about “If the block is entered recursively” is irrelevant. There is no recursive entry here. That text is important because it discusses the situation in which multiple instances of variable exist simultaneously. That is not the case here.

Comment: Haha please stop, I think this was a good answer!

Comment: I agree, the block scope of the `for` loop does not "get the control" (of what?) "recursively".

Comment: I tried in `c++` using `const` but not work. `uninitialized const ‘mystruct’ [-fpermissive]`. Without `const` works.

Comment: @HigorMaiaConcessa A constant with the automatic storage duration shall be initialized when it is declared.

Comment: @IanAbbott The for loop passes the control to its sub-statement recursively in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Can you give an example?

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: @HigorMaiaConcessa This question is about C, not C++.

Comment: @HigorMaiaConcessa An example is shown in the code snippet in the question.

Comment: Vlad, sure ignore my comment. It seems that you answer the question in OPs mind. Whether you answered any of those they asked is not important. ;-) Have an upvote for mindreading. (seriously)

Comment: Okay, I tried in `C`, but not work. Error: `error: assignment of member ‘integer’ in read-only object`

Comment: Vlad, I take "entered recursively" to mean the code in the block entering itself (i.e. by a recursive function call).

Comment: My [code](https://codeshare.io/stackoverflow67870830).

Comment: @HigorMaiaConcessa The code you linked to does not have an initializer for `mystruct`, but has assignments to members of `mystruct`. The errors are from assignment to members of a read-only object, not from initialization of a read-only object.

Comment: @IanAbbott The word recursively in this case has the meaning of repeatedly.

Comment: @HigorMaiaConcessa Initialization and assignment are two different things. As I already wrote you shall initialize a constant variable in its declaration. What is unclear?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't know why you would think it has that meaning. There are already words for that: "iteratively", "repeatedly" or "repetitively".